# Call AWS Lambda function via HTTP

Tags: http, aws-lambda

Does AWS Lambda support HTTP (not HTTPS)?

I'm working with a terrible legacy system that doesn't support HTTPS and would like to have it call an AWS Lambda. I'm aware the ideal is to move to HTTPS, but unfortunately I have very limited control over the system and this is simply not an option.

I'd prefer not to use a solution like routing via an proxy system that converts the request to HTTPS if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an application load balancer that is internet facing and accepts the HTTP requests.

Configure your target group to have lambda as its target.
Now you can send the request to the load balancer that you have created which in turn would call the lambda.

[services-alb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html)

[lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers/)